# Doubts in try catch block in C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

the question was :

The application should ask the user for the total number of tickets to be booked. while the booking the tickets if the total number of booked tickets exceeds the available tickets, the application should raise an exception.  I don't know why it is not showing an error when I do this I came up with this solution:

```
using System;    
namespace Ticket
{
    class blah
    {
        public void abc()
        {    
            int numberOfTickets;
            int numberOfAvailableTickets=10;
            int cost = 100;
            int pay;
            Console.WriteLine("how many tickets do you need");
            numberOfTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            try
            {
                if (numberOfTickets < numberOfAvailableTickets)
                {
                    pay = 100 * numberOfTickets;
                    Console.WriteLine("Pay please");
                    Console.WriteLine(pay);
                }                
            }                
            if( numberOfTickets>numberOfAvailableTickets)
            {                 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

}

 class Theater
 {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            blah hi = new blah();
            hi.abc();
            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"if the total number of booked tickets exceeds the available tickets, the application should raise an exception"* - No, it most definitely shouldn't. Raise exceptions in situations that are unexpected, not because some number hits a natural boundary.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right but this seems more like homework...

Comment: you have mixed if and try-catch. The code doesn't read any meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not even sure that the code you show even compiles... try this

```
using System;

namespace Ticket
{
    class blah
    {
        public void abc()
        {

            int numberOfTickets;
            int numberOfAvailableTickets=10;
            int cost = 100;
            int pay;
            Console.WriteLine("how many tickets do you need");
            numberOfTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            try
            {

            if( numberOfTickets>numberOfAvailableTickets)
                throw new Exception ("Not enough Tickets available!");


                    pay = 100 * numberOfTickets;
                    Console.WriteLine("Pay please");
                    Console.WriteLine(pay);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}
    class Theater
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            blah hi = new blah();
            hi.abc();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

It [`throw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)s an [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) if the the entered number exceeds the available tickets...

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the usage of the throwing an object which means! :( .

Answer (score 2):

The question is telling you to throw an exception if the booked number exceeds the available number.

So you don't need any `try` or `catch` in abc (I really hope these names aren't in your real code).  You can also remove the `if (numberOfTickets < numberOfAvailableTickets)` (but keep the code inside.

Above:

```
pay = 100 * numberOfTickets;
```

move up:

```
if( numberOfTickets>numberOfAvailableTickets)
{
```

Inside the `if` put:

```
throw new ArgumentException("numberOfTickets is greater than numberOfAvailableTickets");
```

You can change ArgumentException to a [custom exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx) if desired

Also note if you're using a `catch`, it must always be immediately after a try or another `catch`.  You can't have an `if` between.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

In `Main`, you can either catch that exception, or let it terminate the app (it's not clear from what you provided).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to raise an exception :

```
if( numberOfTickets>numberOfAvailableTickets)
     throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't explicitly throw the exception. Unless you do that, the compiler sees nothing wrong with your code, as by default it would only throw exceptions which actually affect the running state of your program.

Although this is a 'quick fix' so to say, just adding a `throw new Exception();` where you want the exception to be thrown will work.

However, ideally, I would recommend creating a custom Exception class for this purpose. But the previous line should work anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove the try & catch and simple use MessageBox.

```
if (numberOfAvaiableTickets < numberOfTickets)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number of tickets exceeded", "ErrorWindow");
}
else
{
     pay = 100 * numberOfTickets;
     Console.WriteLine("Pay please");
     Console.WriteLine(pay);
}
```